# how to extract certain columns

Tags: text-processing

I have a data set and I need to extract certain columns using linux
for example

I have the following columns

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

and I want to keep col 1 then select col 2 and skip 3,4,5 the and select col 6 and skip 7,8,9 and select col 10 and so one
so I want to skip 3 columns each time

here is part of the data

```
Composite Element REF   Beta_value  Gene_Symbol Chromosome  Genomic_Coordinate  Beta_value  Gene_Symbol Chromosome  Genomic_Coordinate
cg00000029  0.188204193 RBL2    16  53468112    0.166988369 RBL2    16  53468112
cg00000108  NA  C3orf35 3   37459206    NA  C3orf35 3   37459206
cg00000109  NA  FNDC3B  3   171916037   NA  FNDC3B  3   171916037
cg00000165  0.111512805 NA  1   91194674    0.542004657 NA  1   91194674
cg00000236  0.938647003 VDAC3   8   42263294    0.935845645 VDAC3   8   42263294
cg00000289  0.633428798 ACTN1   14  69341139    0.733281344 ACTN1   14  69341139
cg00000292  0.65556936  ATP2A1  16  28890100    0.358096457 ATP2A1  16  28890100
cg00000321  0.191278127 SFRP1   8   41167802    0.509407035 SFRP1   8   41167802
cg00000363  0.135746609 NA  1   230560793   0.120685168 NA  1   230560793
cg00000622  0.017719646 NIPA2   15  23034447    0.018611505 NIPA2   15  23034447
cg00000658  0.891647766 MAN1B1  9   139997924   0.904048927 MAN1B1  9   139997924
cg00000714  0.061226142 TSEN34  19  54695678    0.071011447 TSEN34  19  54695678
cg00000721  0.950283919 LRRC16A 6   25282779    0.952309685 LRRC16A 6   25282779
cg00000734  0.058200906 CNBP    3   128902377   0.05981105  CNBP    3   128902377
cg00000769  0.025102512 DDX55   12  124086477   0.028169739 DDX55   12  124086477
```

I need to keep the first column "Composite Element REF" and then select only the Beta_Value so it is column 2 then column 6 and so on and the total number of columns is 1373

Thank you

Comment: are the number of columns unknown, or definitely 10?

Comment: just from a pattern point of view, you're keeping column 1, *then* starting a pattern of "keep a column, skip 3 columns" (repeat)?

Comment: can you provide more extended input text? It's unclear how exactly should look your expected result

Comment: there are 1373 columns in the data set.

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes i keep column 1 and start from column 2 repeat for the 1373 columns

Comment: you should show *representative* data in your question -- this latest version is not comma-separated at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[This is based on you - current - space separated sample data]*

You could use an array slice in `perl`, selecting the indices using `grep` and some modulo arithmetic:

```
perl -anle 'print join "\t", $F[0], @F[grep { !($_ % 4 - 1) } 1..$#F]' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is lacking a bit of details. 
I assume it is something found in either a text file or from a pipe.

The quick and dirty use of filtering columns would be `awk`

Since your question is hold basic, I will focus on that:

```
$ echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" |awk -F, '{print $1 "," $2 "," $6 "," $10;}'
1,2,6,10
```

The `-F,` is required to declare the comma as a field separator. 
`$0` would be the whole input
`$1` the first column
`$2` the second 
...

If your input data differs from your example, please be more specific.

Comment: i have 1373 columns so this won't work for all the columns

Answer (score 3):

For an awk-based solution:

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{ printf $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=4) { printf OFS $i }; print "";}' marwah.input
```

Comment: If the data is not comma-separated, then just remove the `-v ...` assignments.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/(,[^,]*)(,[^,]*){3}/\1/g' yourfile.txt
```

will keep columns 1,2,6,10,14,18 and so on. I hope this is what you expect.

Comment: where should i put the file name?

Comment: At the end, after the script. See `man sed`

Comment: @MarwahSoliman Did it work? Something still wrong?

Comment: I used the perl solution and it worked I will test your code and let you know